# How to short List having WebElement inside it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

I am getting some value from a HTML Table. I am able to print the values but not able to figure out a way by which i can sort them alphabetically.

Code which i used-

```
List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='user-questions lines']/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
for(WebElement s : lst) {
    System.out.println(s.getText()); //This line prints the value
    String[] ss = new String[lst.size()];
    int i=0;
    if(s.getText() != null) {
        ss[i]=s.getText();
        System.out.println(ss[1]); // But here i am getting null
    }
    i++;
}
```

First i tried to sort it using `Collections.sort(lst)` but got an error message:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List).

Then i tried to put the string value inside a String array and later sort it but here i am getting null value when i tried to put the value into the String array

Comment: As WebElement does not implement the `Comparable` interface you need to call the `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` method. In your Comparator you need to defined how to sort the WebElements.

Answer (score 1):

Today i was stuck in the same thing and found this question asked a way back at the start of this year. When i tried the solutions given i got a NullPointerException.

I wrote a small code and now i am able to short the webelements accoriding to the Natural alphabetical order. Here is the code-

```
  //Here storing the WebElements in the List
  List<WebElement> lst  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("WebElement XPath"));
   //Here creating a String array
   String[] str = new String[lst.size()];
    for (int i = 0 ; i<str.length ; i++){
        str[i] = driver.findElements(By.xpath("WebElement XPath")).get(i).getText();
    }//for
    Arrays.sort(str);
    for(String strr: str){
        System.out.println(strr);
    }
    driver_1.close();
    driver_1.quit();

    }//try
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();    
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();  
    }//catch
```

First i stored the webelements in the List. Then i created a String array for sorting.In the first for loop i stored the string which i got from the website. After that i sorted them using Arrays.sort method

In the advance for loop i am printing the output.

As i can see the question is very old and if during this time you got much better answer then please share it.

Comment: Seems like your code is missing the opening `try {` for the try-catch block. By the way: I'd use indentation rather than the `//for`, `//try` and `//catch` comments at the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You getting null at    `System.out.println(ss[1]);`
because:
 `ss[i]=s.getText();` always put in `ss[0]`, because: 
 before if  `int i=0;`.
So `ss[1]` always empty.

To solve it put `int i=0;` before `for(WebElement s : lst)`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `i` outside foreach loop. and sysout `ss[i]`. On your first loop execution obviously `ss[1]` will be `null`.

Another way around is:

```
List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='user-questions lines']/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
String[] str = new String[lst.size()];
int i = 0;
for (WebElement ele : lst) {
    if(ele.getText()!=null)
        str[i] = ele.getText();
    i++;
}
Arrays.sort(str); // to sort the array of strings
```